# In C++, WriteProcessMemory will not change value outside of VisualStudio

Tags: c++, winapi

It changes the value while it's ran inside of Visual studio, but if I build the program and run the executable it does not actually change the value. Here is the code:

```
using namespace std;

DWORD pid;
DWORD players = 0x00883D70;
int playerCount = 0;
int readValue = 0;
int firstTime = 0;
int main()
{
    HWND hWnd = FindWindowA(0, ("Diablo II"));
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &pid);
    HANDLE pHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, TRUE, pid);
    if (firstTime == 0)
    {
        cout << "This is a tool to set the player count in Diablo II: Lord of Destruction v1.14D" << endl;
        cout << "This tool was made by xElite_V." << endl;
        cout << "You can set a number between 0 and 255 for player difficulty:" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "You can set a number between 0 and 255 for player difficulty:" << endl;
    }
    firstTime = 1;
    cin >> playerCount;
    WriteProcessMemory(pHandle, (LPVOID)players, &playerCount, sizeof(playerCount), 0);
    main();
}
```

So I don't understand why it wouldn't do the same thing as it would while it's in visual studio.

Comment: Now would be a good time to add error checking to all of the Windows and input functions to find out where the problem is. Your infinitely recursive main function will not end well, consider moving your code to a different function.

Comment: Add error checking and do some debugging.

Comment: [To open a handle to another process and obtain full access rights, you must enable the SeDebugPrivilege privilege. For more information, see Changing Privileges in a Token.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/process-security-and-access-rights). When your program runs inside VS, it's probably getting the privilege set because VS sets it to be able to debug programs. When you run it independently, VS isn't setting it up, and your code isn't doing it either.

Comment: [also this could help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366898(v=vs.85).aspx) , most likely it is protected . try like the comments before me to validate the errors you get and if the write to process returns error try getting it [by something like this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Not one of your immediate issues, but do read [\[basic.start.main\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main#3).

Comment: @ Ninja: It's purposely meant to loop, it's to adjust the difficulty in-game.
@ Hefferman: How would I do this? It also works perfectly as intended in VS and doesn't modify the program outside VS if it makes a difference.
@ Coffin: Is there a way to do this without too much editing? Also I kind of have PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS in my process handler.
@ 1779374: I haven't an idea how this would work, I'm sort of new to C++, actually only started it today. Is there a way to use the WINAPI or is it just a set of properties to leave above the main()?

Comment: Your expectations are unrealistic. You've never done any C++ or winapi until today, and this is your first challenge? You don't check the return values of any winapi function calls for errors. The documentation tells you what to check for.

Comment: @Jerry That's actually an interesting observation, because (a) you're likely right, and (b) why does VS give _the program being debugged_ that privilege when it only actually needs it for itself.  Enquiring minds want to know.

Comment: @RetiredNinja _Your infinitely recursive main function will not end well_  It won't end _at all_, lol.

Comment: @PaulSanders: You are wrong. It *will* end, unless you are running on a system with infinite memory.

Comment: @PaulSanders: My guess is that if that's how things happened (and I'm not really *sure* it is) that it simply happened by accident.

Comment: @IInspectable Oh well, have it your way :)  Woohoo, 4k rep :)

Comment: @Jerry Yes, I agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost certainly have a permissions problem, but since your code doesn't check for errors properly, nobody can actually tell you for sure.

There's actually a bunch of stuff you need to do to get this to work, and there's some code that does that here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51346951/5743288

Note that this is calling `ReadProcessMemory` but the idea is the same.

Comment: @WilliamJohnson yw